# NODE.JS(TYPESCRIPT) Property 'req' does not exist on type 'NodeModule'

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am having issues using this.status and this.req in my subfile

I initialize the route index like this

```
router.use(response);
```

my index file is below

```
import {Request,Response,NextFunction} from 'express'

module.exports = function(req:Request, res:Response, next:NextFunction){
    const responseTypes = {
        unprocessable: require('./unprocessable')
    };

    res = {...res, ...responseTypes};
    next();
};
```

here is my unprocessable.ts file

```
import log from '../logger'
import queue from '../queue'

module.exports = function (data, message) {
    log.warn('Sending unprocessable entity response: ', data, message || 'unprocessable entity');
    const req = this.req;
    const res = this;

    // Dump it in the queue
    const response = { response: { status: 'error', data: data, message: message ? message : 'unprocessable entity' } };
    response.requestId = req.requestId;

    queue.add('logResponse', response);

    if (data !== undefined && data !== null) {
        if (Object.keys(data).length === 0 && JSON.stringify(data) === JSON.stringify({})) {
            data = data.toString();
        }
    }

    if (data) {
        this.status(422).json({ status: 'error', data: data, message: message ? message : 'unprocessable entity' });
    } else {
        this.status(422).json({ status: 'error', message: message ? message : 'unprocessable entity' });
    }
};
```

It complains about the following in the unprocessable.ts file

> Property 'status' does not exist on type 'NodeModule' if I use this.status
>
> Property 'req' does not exist on type 'NodeModule' if I use this.req

I have no idea how to solve it as I am new to typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript does for the most part not know what you refer to when you are using the `this` keyword.

You can however tell typescript what you mean by `this`, e.g:

```js
function someFunction(this: object) {
  // do something with this
}
```

In your case, `this` refers to an object that extends `Response` from express so what you could do is:

```js
const { Response } = require('express');

interface IModifiedResponse extends Response {
  // define your properties here
  unprocessable: (data: object, message: string) => void
}

function unprocessable(this: IModifiedResponse, data: object, message: string) {
  // use this as in your function
}
```

However I do not know what this.req refers to as Response does not have a req property. See [ExpressJS docs](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res)

Hope this answers helps :).